# Spring Boot Micro-services, mixing local and remote services

Tags: java, spring-boot, distributed-computing, microservices, netflix-eureka

I'm starting with micro-services using Spring Boot.  I've read up on the subject matter and adapted examples from various source. ([Spring-cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html), [Microservice registration and discovery with Spring Cloud and Netflix's Eureka](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka), [Microservices with Spring](https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring), etc).

What I would like to do is have micro-services (local only) interact with micro-services on a remote or centralised server. I realise that the whole idea is to have a distributive architecture and some underlining communication network (encapsulated), but my project requires some localised machine controllers and "off-site" information processing:

```
+-----+
| A.1 |----------+
+-----+          |
+-----+          |         +---+
| A.2 |----------+---------| C |
+-----+          |         +---+
+-----+          |         +---+
| B.1 |==========+---------| D |
+-----+                    +---+
```

There are multiple machine controllers A (e.g. A.1, A.2) and B (e.g. B.1, B.2 etc) "on-site". Where, for example, A.1 and A.2 are identical but on separate physical PCs.  For A and B; each runs its own localised Eureka registration server and a collection of (very specialised) micro-services that interacts with one-another.  C and D are collections of micro-services that are "off-site"/ cloud based.  A will call micro-services on/at C and B on/at C and D.

Learning is fun and I would appreciate a pointing in the direction of more (specialised) articles that might help me to figure this out.

Comment: you saw this video from josh long? [Spring Cloud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFDYdslOvu8)

Comment: @Patrick Nope, will look at it at home ;-)

Comment: I guess the easiest and quickest way is for A and B to do web service / "standard" rest calls to a url?